# Where can I find a good Robocode tutorial?

Tags: java, robotics, robocode

I have really enjoyed playing [Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) with my first robot. Now I want to make something a little more exciting. What's the best tutorial on making advanced robots?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried [robowiki.net](http://robowiki.net/w/index.php?title=Main_Page)? They have a ton of resources including advanced topics like:

- [Pattern Matching](http://robowiki.net/w/index.php?title=Pattern_Matching)
- [Clustering](http://robowiki.net/w/index.php?title=Dynamic_Clustering)
- [Statistical partitioning](http://robowiki.net/w/index.php?title=GuessFactor_Targeting_Tutorial)

A number of the top bots in the [Roborumble](http://darkcanuck.net/rumble/Rankings?version=1&game=roborumble) are also [open source](http://robowiki.net/w/index.php?title=Category:Open_Source_Bots).

When you're ready, be sure to [enter your robot in the rumble](http://robowiki.net/w/index.php?title=RoboRumble/Starting_With_RoboRumble).